# Как адаптивно верстать svg

Tags: html, css, svg

Я не понимаю как адаптировать `svg`
1) Я задаю родителю, в котором лежит `svg` `width: 200px`, а родитель уменьшает свою ширину, не понимаю как с этим бороться
2) При уменьшении экрана, 2 элемента, которые в середине, уменьшаются сильнее, хотя для всех элементов я задавал одинаковые css правила.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я собираюсь адаптировать это под разные разрешения, c помощью `@media` запросов, возможно ли это сделать только из `css`?
Это можно посмотреть здесь: https://mihinov.github.io/#team (проскролльте чуть вниз, там будут эти круги анимированные)

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.teamwork {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
}

.section {
    color: #505050;
    padding: 0 30px;
    display: block;
}

.cards__progress__bar {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-around;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 80px;
}

.progress__container {
 width: 200px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 padding: 0 25px;
}

.progressbar__track {
 fill: transparent;
 stroke: #ededed;
 stroke-width: 2px;
}

.progressbar__thumb {
 fill: transparent;
 stroke-dasharray: 0 1;
 stroke: #ff0036;
 stroke-width: 2px;
 transform-origin: center;
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.progressbar text {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.progressbar text tspan {
 fill: #ff0036;
}

/*************** 

PROGRESS__TEXT

****************/

.progress__text {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.progress__title {
 color: #262626;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 600;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.progress__subtitle {
 color: #505050;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700|Raleway:400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<section class="section teamwork">
  <div class="cards__progress__bar">

    <div class="progress__container">
      <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
        <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
        <circle class="progressbar__thumb" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30" data-circle="90"></circle>
        <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle><tspan>0</tspan>%</text>
      </svg>
      <div class="progress__text">
        <div class="progress__title">Photoshop</div>
        <div class="progress__subtitle">Donec luctus tortor in placerat faucibus</div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- .progress__container -->

    <div class="progress__container">
      <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
        <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
        <circle class="progressbar__thumb" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30" data-circle="80"></circle>
        <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle><tspan>0</tspan>%</text>
      </svg>
      <div class="progress__text">
        <div class="progress__title">HTML</div>
        <div class="progress__subtitle">Donec luctus tortor in placerat faucibus</div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- .progress__container -->

    <div class="progress__container">
      <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
        <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
        <circle class="progressbar__thumb" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30" data-circle="70"></circle>
        <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle><tspan>0</tspan>%</text>
      </svg>
      <div class="progress__text">
        <div class="progress__title">PHP</div>
        <div class="progress__subtitle">Donec luctus tortor in placerat faucibus</div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- .progress__container -->

    <div class="progress__container">
      <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
        <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
        <circle class="progressbar__thumb" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30" data-circle="90"></circle>
        <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle><tspan>0</tspan>%</text>
      </svg>
      <div class="progress__text">
        <div class="progress__title">WordPress</div>
        <div class="progress__subtitle">Donec luctus tortor in placerat faucibus</div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- .progress__container -->

  </div> <!-- .cards__progress__bar -->
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня `svg` так вёл себя, из-за того, что он был зажат `padding`. 
Каждому `.progress__container` был задан `padding: 0 25px;`. Я убрал это, поведение чуть поменялось, но не совсем. Я решил убрать у всех элементов `padding`, которые были на странице.
 У `.section` был `padding: 0 30px`. При малом экране я убрал эти паддинги и svg стал вести себя так, как нужно